# download fileinput() after data manipulation in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny App and after some data manipulations, I would like to download `mytable`. Many thanks in advance.

```
   library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = 'Benvenuti',
  tabPanel('read.me', column(3,
                             
                             h3("Daily Data Manipulation"),
                             
                             h3("title1"),
                             tags$a("Upload data.xlsx")
  )),
  
  tabPanel(title = "title2", 
           sidebarPanel( width = 2, fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                                              accept = c(".xlsx")),
                         numericInput("ID", "Enter the starting ID number:",
                                      value = 1, min = -Inf, max = Inf),
                         downloadButton("Download.mytable", "Download mytable")
           ), 
           
           mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId = "mytable"))
  ) ) 



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data.Consenso <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if(!is.null(inFile)) {
    readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    #read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
  }
})


output$mytable <- renderTable({
  
  dat <- data.Consenso()
  if(!is.null(dat))
  {
    dat$Tipo <- 3
    
    dat
  }
}) 

mytable2 <- reactive({mytable})

output$Download.mytable  <- downloadHandler(
  
  filename = function() { 
    paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
  },
  
  content = function(file) {
    
    write.csv(mytable2(), file)
    
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error

```
Warning: Error in <reactive:mytable2>: object 'mytable' not found
  3: runApp
  2: print.shiny.appobj
  1: <Anonymous>
```

photo
[image]

Comment: You call `mytable()` but should probably be using `data.Consenso()`.

Comment: In general, questions on SO need to contain a clear problem statement, including warnings, errors, misbehavior, incorrect results, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `mytable()`  but it is not defined anywhere. Assuming you are taking the original data and somehow modifying things, you need something like this:

```r
mytable <- reactive({
  req(data.Consenso())
  something <- data.Consenso() |>
    subset(somevar > 5) |>
    transform(newvar = somevar - 42)
  something
})
```

I'm using base-R pipes and such, this is just a demonstration that *this* is where you would do whatever data manipulation is needed before allowing the user to download a newly-created CSV.

Comment: Many thanks. But I would like to download after I did data manipulation. So in this case my.table.  not data.Consenso() which is the same as what I uploaded.

Comment: okay, then you need to _create_ `mytable <- reactive(...)` to be able to use `mytable()`.

Comment: the output somehowe .htm and at the end cant open or download it.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please edit your question and add more content, including the actual problem (errors/warnings) and code you've fixed since my last comment.

Comment: Okay @SeymaKalay, perhaps you need `mytable <- reactive({ ... })` where `...` is your "data manipulation". What are you needing to do to the data?

Comment: thanks a lot but i am gonna delete and reask this question seems it is not working

Comment: That's your choice. If/when you ask for this again ... the error is clear, you have not defined `mytable <- ...` anywhere, so I suggest you go down that road _first_, since that error message is clear enough.

Comment: Could you edit this to your respond ? So i may get a functioning code. What i am trying is not working.